# Disposing each socket client that is connected to the socket server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have just recently started development for a server - multiple clients application using Socket.

The server doesn't need to keep track of the connected clients; If there is a client that requests for connection, server accepts it. If there is a request from any client (to get some data), server will response to that client.

```
/// <summary>
/// Callback when server accepts a new incoming connection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="result">Incoming connection result object.</param>
private void AcceptedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
  try
  {
      Socket clientSocket = _socket.EndAccept(result); // Asynchronously accepts an incoming connection attempt

      if (clientSocket.Connected)  // Check if the client is in 'Connected' state
      {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, // Start listening to client request
                                  ReceiveCallback, state);
      }
      else
      {
            clientSocket.Close();    // Terminate that client's connection
        Log.writeLog("TCPServer(AcceptedCallback)"
                     , "Client's status is not connected.");
      }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Log.writeLog("TCPServer(AcceptedCallback)"
                 , ex.Message);
      clientSocket.Close();
  }
  finally
  {
      Accept(); // Start to accept new connection request
  }
}
```

I have 3 questions about this:

1. For each **BeginReceive** that I create for the newly connected client, does my **server application** creates a new thread/object to hold that client?
2. If after the client is connected, and the network cable is pulled off at the client side and plug back in, the client will connect to the server again and this is considered a new connection on the server, if this scenario occurs again and again, will my server program crashes?
3. Hence, do I need to keep track of each client that is connected to the server, and find a way to track their state so I can call Close/Dispose on them?

So far in my testing for scenario 2, there are no abnormalities detected in my server program, but I hope someone would help clarify this for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it will use a IO completion thread from a pool of threads.
2. No, you can code and should code to cater for this. If something happens on the client side that the OS can detect, it will send a TCP fin/ack to the server. This should result in any BeginXXX method still waiting to go the Async Callback Method. From there your call to EndXXX method should either throw an exception or return zero bytes being read from the socket.
3. This depends on what you mean by keep track of to dispose of them properly. If you mean dispose of them if you detect an error, no, you can put clean up code in your EndXXX methods. If you mean so that you can signal clients gracefully if you shut the server down, then yes.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply uriDium. Based on your reply, I can conclude that: 
1. No additional memory/resources are created for each connected client. 

2. I have a clean-up code to handle situation like  "From there your call to EndXXX method should either throw an exception or return zero bytes being read from the socket.", but there is no need to call Dispose/Close on the client that causes this error (at server program).

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 1. You don't have to create threads, it will be handled by OS. 2. You probably won't have to call close or dispose and if you do you will probably get an ObjectAlreadyDisposed exception. But you can do so and most do anyway to make 100% sure. They just catch the ObjectAlreadyDisposedException because in this case it is almost expected.

Comment: I see, okay, thank you, I consider this case close for now.